# Facebook ios sdk 3.5 openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions don't callback using web login

Tags: ios, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I just switched to Facebook ios sdk 3.5 and trying to authenticate user using

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
    //callback methods
}];
```

I have setup the FacebookAppID, FacebookDisplayName, CFBundleURLSchemes in info.plist file.
And in AppDelegate, i have the following function setup:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                         sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    // add app-specific handling code here
    return wasHandled;
}
```

And now it is able to call the callback block when I'm having facebook account logged in on the iPhone itself, which I think it is used the new route for FBAppCall.

But the problem is when I don't setup my iPhone FB account, the app try to authenticate using safari web view or the FB app, then after the allow access button pressed on safari or the app, my App get called and it showed the Launch image, but it just hang there, and the callback block is never get called.  I'm thinking this a different route for the application handling openurls, but I'm not sure since if i put a break point in the

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

It never get's stopped in the breakpoint.